# How important is quantum mechanics to solid state electronics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, education, electronics

How important is it to know quantum mechanics if one wants a career in solid state electronic devices?

I want to do a PhD in semiconductor physics, but I don't know much quantum mechanics.

What do you think? Should I study a whole undergrad textbook before going into the PhD?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a classical system that behaves like a semiconductor. The governing concept is the band structure of the electrons, and you simply dont get band structure without QM.

Comment: What do you mean by "Should I study a whole undergrad textbook"? What undergraduate degree are taking / have you taken? Presumably your degree already contains a full course in QM? If it doesn't, then it's likely that even throwing a full reading of a textbook at this will not be sufficient.

Comment: It seems like it would be very difficult to get admitted to a semiconductor physics PhD program without having taken at least a course in quantum mechanics.

Comment: What is your education background?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Physics of semiconductors is about electrons and holes in crystals. One needs a sound understanding of quantum mechanics to appreciate their behavior. Yet you don't need to know a lot to get started. You may want to begin with the introductory chapters of such classics as 'Millman and Halkias' or 'Streetman' and find out how far they take you. Once you get sufficiently deep in solid state electronics you will naturally seek to know more quantum mechanics. Please don't let your lack of preparation of QM get in your way.